How to define a struct member function which returns another struct
I have written a simple worksheet program to convert between cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates. When compiled, an error is displayed.
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

#define PI 3.14159

struct Polar;

struct Vector2;

struct Polar{
    double r, theta;

    Vector2 toCartesian(){
        return {r*cos(theta*PI/180), r*sin(theta*PI/180)};
    }  
};

struct Vector2{
    double x,y;

    Polar toPolar(){
        return {sqrt(x*x + y*y), atan(y/x)};
    }
};



int main(){
    std::cout << "Enter Polar coordinates in form of R theta to convert to cartesian: ";
    Polar P;
    std::cin >> P.r >> P.theta;
    Vector2 Pcord;
    Pcord = P.toCartesian();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << "(x,y) = " << Pcord.x << " " << Pcord.y;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

Error message:
exe.cpp: In member function 'Vector2 Polar::toCartesian()':
exe.cpp:14:26: error: return type 'struct Vector2' is incomplete
     Vector2 toCartesian(){
                          ^
exe.cpp: In function 'int main()':
exe.cpp:34:27: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Vector2' and 'void')
     Pcord = P.toCartesian();
                           ^
exe.cpp:19:8: note: candidate: constexpr Vector2& Vector2::operator=(const Vector2&)
 struct Vector2{
        ^~~~~~~
exe.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'const Vector2&'
exe.cpp:19:8: note: candidate: constexpr Vector2& Vector2::operator=(Vector2&&)
exe.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'Vector2&&'*

What is the issue here? At first, I thought this was because the compiler didn't know struct Vector2 exists when going through struct Polar, similar to calling a function declared below from another function, so I used a forward declaration, but the issue is not resolved.

Declaring function does not need full definition of return type but you try to define it inline and that does not work. Define toCartesian function after Polar is fully defined.

"error: return type 'struct Vector2' is incomplete " incomplete means that the forward declaration is inadequate here for the definition of the function. Code can't be generated for the fcn without knowing the definition of Vector2. Try just declaring the fcn in the Polar definition and defining it after the Vector2 definition. See here.

A forward declaration merely tells the compiler that a type exists, but not what that type looks like, so the compiler doesn't known what is needed to create instances of that type.
You are trying to create a Vector2 instance before the compiler knows what Vector2 contains. That is why the error message says Vector2 is an incomplete type.
To accomplish what you are trying to do, you must separate the declaration and definition of Polar::toCartesian() so that you can fully define Vector2 before you can then create an instance of it, eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

#define PI 3.14159

struct Vector2;

struct Polar{
    double r, theta;

    Vector2 toCartesian();
};

struct Vector2{
    double x,y;

    Polar toPolar(){
        return {sqrt(x*x + y*y), atan(y/x)};
    }
};

Vector2 Polar::toCartesian(){
    return {r*cos(theta*PI/180), r*sin(theta*PI/180)};
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Enter Polar coordinates in form of R theta to convert to cartesian: ";
    Polar P;
    std::cin >> P.r >> P.theta;
    Vector2 Pcord;
    Pcord = P.toCartesian();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << "(x,y) = " << Pcord.x << " " << Pcord.y;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

Online Demo

Remembering to put an inline one one or both of those declarations if this is in a header

@Artyer -   The only usage of the inline keyword needed is on the definition of Polar::toCartesian()  (and, then, only essential if that function is defined in a header file that is included by more than once source file  - inline is optional otherwise).   In the code shown, Polar::toPolar() is implicitly inline since it is in a class definition.

Solution:
move the declaration of Vector2 and Polar to headers. and define toCartesian() and toPolar() in implementation files.
For example:
Polar.h
struct Vector2; // a forward declaration to make declaration of toCartesion valid
struct Polar{
    double r, theta;
    Vector2 toCartesian();
};

Polar.cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include "Polar.h"
#include "vector2.h"
Vector2 Polar::toCartesian()
{
    return {r * cos(theta * M_PI / 180), r * sin(theta * M_PI / 180)};
}

Vector2.h
struct Polar;
struct Vector2{
    double x,y;

    Polar toPolar();
};

Vector2.cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include "Polar.h"
#include "vector2.h"
Polar Vector2::toPolar()
{
    return {sqrt(x * x + y * y), atan(y / x)};
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Polar.h>
#include <vector2.h>


int main(){
    std::cout << "Enter Polar coordinates in form of R theta to convert to cartesian: ";
    Polar P;
    std::cin >> P.r >> P.theta;
    Vector2 Pcord;
    Pcord = P.toCartesian();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << "(x,y) = " << Pcord.x << " " << Pcord.y;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

explanation
For cpp, a type should be declared before using it. In the definition of toCartesian() and toPolar() which create a struct object as return values. The object is initialized by initial list, so compiler must know what is contained by this type.
